# Test-WSMan works with localhost, but doesnt work with fully qualified domain name or Hostname

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, winrm

I have a windows 10 1909 Build 18363. Machine, following is what I am observing. This is all on an powershell with elevated permissions.

```
PS C:\Users\mohit.thakral> Test-WSMan -ComputerName localhost


wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0



PS C:\Users\mohit.thakral> Test-WSMan -ComputerName myhostname
Test-WSMan : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150858770" Machine="myhostname.company.com"><f:Message>The client cannot
connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation
for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination
to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". </f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-WSMan -ComputerName myhostname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (dsw024166:String) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.TestWSManCommand
```

I have checked firewall, my winrm listener are listening on all ips. `winrm qc` also works.

What could be other issues.

Comment: that looks rather like a permission problem. what happens if you run the code in an elevated session?

Comment: I am running it as administrator.

Comment: does that mean you are using the administrator account OR that the session you are using is running "as admin" - aka = in an elevated session?

Comment: I am using as admin - aka = in elevated session

Comment: thank you for that added info! [*grin*] you may want to add that very specific info to your Question. i am out of ideas ... so i will go back to lurking.

Comment: No worries I really appreciate your comment :)

Comment: you are most welcome ... and i wish you the best of good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: What is the output of `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Port 5985` and `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName your.fqdn.here. -Port 5985`? It seems like a firewall profile mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

So, the fix was this `setspn -f -q */mymachinename` . Seems like somehow my credentials was not allowing me to connect to any server for winrm. After running this `setspn -f -q */mymachinename` it fixed it